# Condition in 2-way table

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
LOGIN,IMPROVE,EXECNUMBER,RESULT
1002,NO,1,0
1002,NO,2,0
1002,NO,3,0
1002,NO,4,0
1002,NO,5,0
1002,NO,6,0
1002,NO,7,0
1002,NO,8,0
1002,NO,9,0
1002,NO,10,0
1002,NO,11,0
1002,NO,12,26
1002,NO,13,61
1002,NO,14,29
1002,NO,15,30
1002,NO,16,36
1002,NO,17,44
1002,NO,18,36
1002,NO,19,33
1002,NO,20,39
1002,NO,21,44
1002,NO,22,40
1002,NO,23,57
1002,NO,24,61
1002,NO,25,57
1002,NO,26,29
1002,NO,27,33
1002,NO,28,61
1002,NO,29,57
1002,NO,30,30
1002,NO,31,53
1002,NO,32,33
1002,NO,33,53
1002,NO,34,40
1002,NO,35,53
1002,NO,36,45
1002,NO,37,57
1002,NO,38,51
1002,NO,39,47
1002,NO,40,47
1002,NO,41,57
1002,NO,42,43
1002,NO,43,0
1002,NO,44,40
1002,NO,45,66
1002,NO,46,27
1002,NO,47,35
1002,NO,48,61
1002,NO,49,22
1002,NO,50,34
1002,NO,51,61
1002,NO,52,50
1002,NO,53,60
1002,NO,54,40
1002,NO,55,34
1002,NO,56,28
1002,NO,57,39
1002,NO,58,32
1003,YES,1,0
1003,YES,2,0
1004,YES,1,0
1004,YES,2,0
1004,YES,3,0
1004,YES,4,0
1006,YES,1,0
1006,YES,2,0
1006,YES,3,0
1006,YES,4,0
1006,YES,5,0
1006,YES,6,0
1006,YES,7,0
1006,YES,8,0
1006,YES,9,0
1007,NO,1,0
1007,NO,2,0
1007,NO,3,0
1007,NO,4,0
1007,NO,5,0
1007,NO,6,0
1007,NO,7,0
1007,NO,8,0
1007,NO,9,0
1007,NO,10,0
1008,YES,1,0
1008,YES,2,0
1008,YES,3,0
1008,YES,4,0
1008,YES,5,0
1012,YES,1,0
1013,YES,1,4
1013,YES,2,34
1013,YES,3,34
1013,YES,4,30
1013,YES,5,50
1013,YES,6,23
1013,YES,7,42
1013,YES,8,36
1013,YES,9,50
1013,YES,10,20
1013,YES,11,57
1013,YES,12,32
1013,YES,13,47
1013,YES,14,57
1013,YES,15,50
1013,YES,16,30
1014,YES,1,0
1014,YES,2,0
1014,YES,3,0
1014,YES,4,0
1014,YES,5,0
1014,YES,6,0
1014,YES,7,0
1014,YES,8,0
1014,YES,9,0
1014,YES,10,0
1014,YES,11,0
1014,YES,12,0
1014,YES,13,0
1014,YES,14,34
1014,YES,15,57
1014,YES,16,36
1014,YES,17,0
1015,NO,1,0
1015,NO,2,0
1015,NO,3,0
1015,NO,4,0
1015,NO,5,0
1015,NO,6,0
1015,NO,7,0
1015,NO,8,0
1015,NO,9,0
1015,NO,10,0
1015,NO,11,25
1015,NO,12,21
1015,NO,13,33
1015,NO,14,29
1015,NO,15,25
1015,NO,16,40
1015,NO,17,36
1015,NO,18,28
1015,NO,19,47
1015,NO,20,44
1015,NO,21,29
1015,NO,22,19
1015,NO,23,8
1015,NO,24,28
1015,NO,25,47
1015,NO,26,29
1015,NO,27,32
1015,NO,28,16
1015,NO,29,28
1015,NO,30,18
1015,NO,31,36
1015,NO,32,13
1015,NO,33,47
1015,NO,34,27
1016,NO,1,0
1016,NO,2,0
1016,NO,3,0
1016,NO,4,0
1016,NO,5,0
1016,NO,6,0
1016,NO,7,0
1016,NO,8,0
1016,NO,9,0
1016,NO,10,0
1016,NO,11,0
1016,NO,12,0
1016,NO,13,0
1016,NO,14,0
1016,NO,15,0
1016,NO,16,0
1016,NO,17,0
1016,NO,18,0
1016,NO,19,26
1016,NO,20,21
1016,NO,21,22
1016,NO,22,21
1016,NO,23,28
1016,NO,24,30
1016,NO,25,20
```

describing participants executions of an exercise and improving after those executions.
LOGIN is the participant identifier, IMPROVE shows if the particpant improved or not, RESULT ranges from 0 to 66 and is the result of each execution and EXECNUMBER is the execution number of the exercise (meaning first execution, second execution, etc) .

I need to build a cross table with RESULT in X exe (from 0 to 66) and EXECNUMBER on Y exe (from 1 to 58) which I did using this code

```
> myData <- read.csv(file='data.csv',sep=',',header=T)
> res <- table(myData$EXECNUMBER,myData$RESULT)
```

But now I was asked to fill the table with the proportion of people with IMPROVE=YES

Being:
n  number of participants for each execution number and for each result.
m  number of participants for each execution number and for each result and IMPROVE=YES

I need to fill the table with m/n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `subset` function (`?subset`).

```
myDataSubsetYes <- subset(myData, myData$IMPROVE == "SI")
table(myDataSubsetYes$EXECNUMBER, myDataSubsetYes$RESULT)
```

(BTW: there is not any YES in your IMPROVE column)

Comment: Thanks! I corrected the IMPROVE column changing the "SI" values for "YES". Now I have a table filled with the number of participants that IMPROVED for each RESULT and EXECNUMBER but I don't know how to create a table of the same dimensions filled with both those with IMPROVE=YES and IMPROVE=NO, if I had that table I could divide them and get the result I need.

Comment: I think that I will manually build the RESULT table starting from my res table and filling each position RESULT[i,j] with each value obtained with the subset function and that will do the trick. Thanks!